# How to get Model: "sequential" constant in keras model summary

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, modelsummary

I try to do classification in using keras. Every time I run the code, model summary always give increase model sequential index. The code that I use is like this:

```
np.random.seed(0)
tensorflow.random.set_seed(0)

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(100, input_dim= Train_X2_Tfidf.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = Adam (learning_rate=0.01)
model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model1.summary()
```

For example, first run I get model summary like this:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 100)               114900    
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 101       
                                                                 
=================================================================
```

Second run, I get model summary like this:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 100)               114900    
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 101       
                                                                 
=================================================================
```

Numbers in `Output Shape` and `Param #` not change at all, but `Model: "sequential"` change into `Model: "sequential_1"`. How can I always get `Model: "sequential"` every time I run it?

Comment: Why would you need this? its not like the name of the model is used for many things.

Comment: try, `model1 = Sequential(name="sequential")`